# Regular expression help in context of locate command

Tags: regex

I want to search for all the files and directories named "codes".

So  I type   `locate --regex "/<codes "`  as "\<" anchor allows me to restrict the output to the ones that only have "codes" in it. But I get this output:

/usr/share/hplip/base/codes.py

/usr/share/hplip/base/codes.pyc

**/usr/share/lintian/data/files/*incorrect-locale-codes***

**/usr/share/lintian/data/files/*locale-codes***

**/usr/share/pkgconfig/*iso-codes.pc***

Here I have the patterns that have "codes" in them but they are part of a larger word such as "iso-codes". Basically I want a regular expression that allows me to locate files&directories that only have "codes" in them and nothing else

Comment: I don't think you require the '<'. Have you tried just locate --regex "/codes"? That should work for you

Comment: @shridharama Yes I had tried the fix you mentioned it gave me this result : /usr/share/aclocal/codeset.m4

Comment: UPDATE : After looking at all the answers I found this regular expression best suited to my job : "\/codes(\.[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)?$". Thanks to @AlexR for suggesting "\/codes(\.[\w]+)?$" but It seems not to work as expected, However this works for some reason  "\/codes(\.\w+)?$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for "/codes" followed by either a slash, dot or end-of-input:

```
\/codes(\/|\.|$)
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/KMgevUmZc6)

Comment: @alex Aggh. Fixed . Thx

Comment: I'm unsure if a file like `codes.for.characters.multiple.extensions` should be found or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping the extension:

```
\/codes(\.[\w]+)?$
```

This will match `/codes` and `/codes.asdf` with any extension and no double extension. The `$` forces the end of filename so no prefixes are matched. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/fA5rA6/1) for a demo.

Comment: The regex you suggested worked like a charm for finding the directories and the files this is the output it gave me :             /home/prime/codes
/home/prime/Desktop/codes
/home/prime/Desktop/TEproject/codes .However just to test the regular expression I also created another file called "codes.java" in Desktop folder but i think its grouped along with the folder "codes" already present there . However the regex you suggested has helped me in other ways in my project

Comment: I would have upvoted your answer If I had the reputation

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you

```
\/codes\.?\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ7iH8/3)

Comment: This is not going to find any directories named `/codes`.

Comment: @AlexR just gave it another try.

Comment: As long as your regex doesn't look for end-of-input (`$`), it can't work as required. Think about it.

Comment: I tested the regexes of both bohemian and @apgp88 and they both seem to give the same answers